# How do I block all network connections when I lock the screen (and resume when unlocking) in macOS?

Tags: networking, macos, script, firewall, lock-screen

Looking to block all network traffic anytime I am away from the computer. I tried putting the iMac to sleep every time I step away and changed the sleep mode to be hibernation as well changed energy-saving settings to disable network traffic and Wake on LAN but my router reports that my iMac still is doing network communication after I put it to sleep.

Anyways, beyond that I want to block all connections even when the computer is locked.

I could run below command as a script (running it in a tool like EventScripts so it triggers when I lock the screen)

`/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setblockall on` or `off`

The problem is, it won't work unless I `sudo` it. And I don't want to have to put in a password every time I lock the screen so this script runs.

Is there any way around it short of removing the need to provide a password to `sudo` which is a bad idea?

Comment: Is [power nap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032) enabled?

Comment: Power nap is disabled @SaaruLindestøkke as is wake for network access